# Why can't I initialize my array?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

All I'm trying to do is initialize my array to all 0s in C, but my compiler keeps giving me errors (and the errors aren't helpful). The array has 24 entries and the values are floating point values.

```
main()
{

/* Array of users arrival & departure time */
float user_queue[24];

/* Initialize queue to 0 */
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    user_queue[i] = 0.0;
}

/* Simulation time */
float time = 0;
```

The compiler is giving me an error on the "float time" line.  The error goes away if I remove my for loop.

> syntax error : missing ; before type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overrunning the array by 1 element. Try this instead:

```
for(i = 0; i < 24; i++)
```

Change the `<=` to `<`.

**EDIT :** With new information.

You're probably compiling in C89/90 or ANSI C mode. In those older C revisions, variable declarations must be at the start of the function or scope. You can't intermingle declarations and code like that.

Try this:

```
main()
{

    /* Array of users arrival & departure time */
    float user_queue[24];

    float time;  /* Declare up here */

    /* Initialize queue to 0 */
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        user_queue[i] = 0.0;
    }

    /* Simulation time */
    time = 0;
```

Comment: Oops, yea I just fixed that, but I'm still not able to compile.

Comment: Then the error isn't in the code you have provided. You'll need to provide more of the surrounding code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer.  I had no idea C had that type of restriction.

Comment: Yes, but they removed that restriction in C99.

Comment: Is there a standard compiler version that is used for C?  I'd like some more flexibility if possible, but still use C and not use an obscure version (if such a thing exists).  I have Visual Studio 2010, so I assume it has newer compiler versions built into it.

Comment: The problem with Visual Studio is that it only supports C89/90 and MS refuses to add support for C99. So if you have to write C code Visual Studio, you'll have to do it in this old C89/90 standard. For me, it's annoying enough where I just compile all my C code as C++ on Windows. I don't use VLAs so it only takes a few extra casts to make it work.

Comment: I don't need to use Visual Studio.  It's what I used back in school, so it's just what I'm most familiar with.  I can try using Netbeans or Eclipse if one of those supports C99. I think compiling as C++ might be a little too challenging for me.

Comment: Mingw (gcc) will give you a C compiler that runs under Windows and supports C99.

Answer (score 4):

You may not be allowed to declare variables after you have already used expressions. Try moving the declaration of `time` to the top:

```
main()
{

/* Array of users arrival & departure time */
float time, user_queue[24];

/* Initialize queue to 0 */
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    user_queue[i] = 0.0;
}

/* Simulation time */
time = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

For this you don't even need a loop:

```
/* Array of 24 users */
float user_queue[24] = { 0.0 };
```

this will initialize the array to all zeros without the for loop.

Comment: FWIW: your answer is referenced [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113819/repeated-answer-should-i-complain) - might want to chime in 'fore folks get stupid.

Answer (score 2):

`<`, not `<=`, thus:

`for( i = 0; i < 24; i++ )`

When you create an array like this:

`float user_queue[24]`

You are creating an array with 24 elements, numbered 0 through 23.

With respect to your updated code, `float time = 0;` needs to come at the beginning of the `main(){.....}` block.  C's prior to C99 (with the exception of some implementations) didn't let you declare variables except at the beginning of their enclosing scope/block.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
float user_queue[24] = {0};
```